# Need to remove for loop to vectorize code and run faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a school assignment where I have to create a classifier (kNN). I attempted doing so and it is super slow. I need to speed it up without using loops but I am unsure how to do it. I have training data and labels. I also have test data.

I have already created a function to perform the classification.

```
label=classifier(train, trainlabel, testvector)
```

Where train is the training data which is an nxm matrix.
trainlabel is the labels which is mx1.
testvector is a single sample which is nx1.

The full testdata that I must predict is some nxk matrix. Right now I am creating a loop to extract columns and pass it into my classifier. Please see code below.

```
for i in range(0, numoftestsamples):
    testvector=testdata[:,i]
    predictions[i]= classifier(train, trainlabel, testvector)
```

Is there any way to vectorize this so it runs faster on python?

Comment: If `classifier` only works with one `testvector` at a time, there's nothing else that you can do.

Comment: while you may not *vectorize* your code, you could make it run in parallel. The easiest (if it works) would be to use `prange` from [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#numba-parallel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

As @hpaulj says, you'll need to do the optimization in the classifier such that it operates on the full matrix `testdata` at once, rather than on a column (`testvector`) at a time. Then your `for` loop would be replaced with,

```
predictions = classifier(train,trainlabel,testdata)
```

You could also parallelize the operations on the column vectors, and there are a number of ways to do this. Staying in vanilla python, there is the `multiprocessing` module that would make this pretty straightforward. However, depending on how compute intensive `classifier` is, one method may out do another.